# Autofac Scoping when Singleton Scoped Object resolves from ComponentContext

Tags: asp.net, autofac

We're having a basic issue with scoping using Autofac. In our scenario, we have some repositories that are singleton scoped. Those repositories are injected with an IDbContextProvider (which is also singleton scoped). The IDbContextProvider is just a wrapper around an injected Autofac IComponentContext. When a DbContext is needed, it is requested from the DBContextProvider by the repository. DbContext is scoped to "lifetimescope", basically per request since this is a Web Api.

So the idea is that the repositories can be singleton scoped as there aren't that many of them and the scoping of the DBContext is managed by Autofac as "per request". This relies on the premise that the Autofac ComponentContext should understand the "leaf" context that it is currently in and return the correct DbContext. I have been told by a coworker who suggested this strategy that this is the behavior exhibited by StructurMap (obviously a different product). To me it makes sense that Autofac would resolve the current "leaf" context and return the proper DbContext, but we're seeing concurrency issues with the DbContext, which leads me to conclude that the IComponentContext is pinned to the singleton that owns it and is therefore returning the same DbContext instance.

```
//This is singleton scoped
public class DbContextProvider : IDbContextProvider
{

    private readonly IComponentContext _componentContext;

    public DbContextProvider(IComponentContext componentContext)
    {
        _componentContext = componentContext;
    }

    public TDbContext GetDbContext<TDbContext>() where TDbContext : IDbContext
    {
        //DbContext is scoped PerLifetimeScope but the component context
        //appears to only understand the context of the singleton that owns 
        //it and returns the same instance no matter the overall context
        //under which is is requested.
        return _componentContext.Resolve<TDbContext>();
    }

}
```

Is there a way to accomplish what we're going for here or is the only course of action to scope the entire dependency tree as PerLifetimeScope to get the proper behavior.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

`IComponentContext` resolve with related lifetime but related lifetime is singleton here, so it will be resolved in container. You should use `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService`

```
public class DbContextProvider : IDbContextProvider
{


    public DbContextProvider()
    {

    }

    public TDbContext GetDbContext<TDbContext>() where TDbContext : IDbContext
    {
        //DbContext is scoped PerLifetimeScope but the component context
        //appears to only understand the context of the singleton that owns 
        //it and returns the same instance no matter the overall context
        //under which is is requested.
        return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService.Resolve<TDbContext>();
    }

}
```

You can check this [article](https://robdmoore.id.au/blog/2013/03/23/resolving-request-scoped-objects-into-a-singleton-with-autofac/) also.

Comment: Doesn't this depend on having an HTTP context available?  This functionality is reused between web api and non-web event handlers, so it won't work to depend on something that requires HttpContext.

Comment: Hımm in web api current lifetime is http request. But in non-web are you creating lifetime before resolving on top ? If you create I'll test and edit my answer to work with both. If you don't start new lifetime and directly resolve from container, I don't think you can acvhive this.